# Can you list all direct search methods to estimate parameters?

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, optimization

Direct search methods (also called derivative-free) are function minimization techniques that do not rely on a function's gradient to find the minimum. More importantly, they can be used to solve non-smooth optimization problems, which can be then used in parameter estimation (e.g., xxx).

As nearly every statistician will recognize, the most commonly used method is the Nelder-Mead, 1965 [(see here for a description)](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nelder-Mead_algorithm). 
The `optim` function in R implements the Nelder-Mead method.

Here, I'd like to create a complete list (with strengths and defects) of other approaches and how to use them. Can you help?

Comment: Typically, shopping-list questions are frowned upon, so I wouldn't be surprised if this gets closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll recommend the survey paper

[Tamara G. Kolda, Robert Michael Lewis, and Virginia Torczon.  Optimization by direct search: new perspectives on some classical and modern methods](http://dx.doi.org/doi:10.1137/S003614450242889)

and this book:

[Andrew R. Conn, Katya Scheinberg, and Luis N. Vicente.  Introduction to Derivative-Free Optimization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898716683)

Comment: Nelder-Mead simplex method, as derivative-free, was adviced somewhere[do't have link] as preferable in comparison with GrigSearchCV... didn't try it yet... but thanks for the link

Answer (score 1):

Hyperparameter search uses a very wide variety of optimization methods. In my opinion, Nelder-Mead is often a poor choice because hyperparameter response surfaces are usually not smooth with tons of local optima. In my experience, Nelder-Mead almost always gets stuck in poor local optima (in the context of optimizing hyperparameters for machine learning methods, so ymmv).

Common methods include:

- Nelder-Mead
- particle swarm optimization
- genetic algorithms
- harmonic search
- racing algorithms
- EGO
- Bayesian optimization
- ...

Many of the metaheuristic methods mentioned above are offered in [Optunity](http://optunity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/solvers.html), while several other packages offer Bayesian optimization (e.g. [Hyperopt](http://jaberg.github.io/hyperopt/), [SMAC](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/beta/Projects/SMAC/) and [BayesOpt](http://rmcantin.bitbucket.org/html/)).